# Need to search value using without space word

Tags: php, mysql

I need to search word like 'Galaxy S Duos' using search keyword 'galaxysduos'. Kindly provide me the solution in PHP Mysql Query.

Comment: This is pretty raw mysql so be careful to test thoroughly: `IF STRING IS SIMILAR IN NATURE TO 'galaxysduos' THEN RETURN, USING PHP... ENSURE NO SPACE WORD`

Comment: `$keyword = str_replace(" ", "", strtolower($keyword));`?

Comment: @putvande: lower is not required. *collation* is case insensitive by default in database.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE REPLACE(fieldname," ","")="galaxysduos"
```

Comment: Since you're answering seriously... you'll need `LOWER()` in there chief, and a `LIKE`.

Comment: Nope that doesn't matter, any case will do for most server setups

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing me quick solutions

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky took a look into it. Interesting!

Answer (score 0):

try this added some modifiction of @Hanky's answer

```
SELECT * FROM `yout_table` WHERE LOWER(REPLACE(`your_field`," ",""))="galaxysduos"
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `yout_table` WHERE REPLACE(LOWER(`your_field`)," ","")="galaxysduos"
```

Comment: You don't have to `LOWER` it, any case will do

Comment: @Dormouse: No that too is not required. Because `collation` is *case insensitive* by default in most of server setups.